# Can I set the stroke style in Google Maps Data Layers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find a way to change a stroke style of lines in Google Maps Data Layers. In [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-style), the examples shows how to create polygons, and change the stroke width and the fill color of the polygons. However, I cannot find the way to change the stroke style of contour lines to, say, dashed lines. Is it possible to change the stroke style?

Comment: You can change the stroke style if you use native google.maps.Polygon objects to display the data.

Comment: [You can only make dashed google.maps.Polylines](http://jsfiddle.net/exqh4opk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the full definition of the `StyleOptions` object literal [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.StyleOptions). Unfortunately although you can set stroke width, colour and opacity, there is no way to specify broken strokes per your question.